# Shortening jQuery 3 way selects (+class toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery

on a change of first select, second select options are being dynamically changed. How can I shorten it (jQuery or vanilla JS)? It is 3 way street - therefore class toggle is not an option?

```js
$(function () {
    $("#selectBox").on("change", function () {
        if ($("#selectBox").val() === "widget") {
            $("#formSelectColour").removeClass("d-none");
            $('#selectWidget option[value="liveAndAverages"]').addClass("d-none");
            $('#selectWidget option[value="energy"]').removeClass("d-none");
            $('#selectWidget option[value="alerts"]').removeClass("d-none");
        } else {
            $("#selectWidget").val("live");
            $("#formSelectColour").addClass("d-none");
            $('#selectWidget option[value="liveAndAverages"]').removeClass("d-none");
            $('#selectWidget option[value="energy"]').addClass("d-none");
            $('#selectWidget option[value="alerts"]').addClass("d-none");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="formSelectBox" class="form-group">
                <label for="selectBox">Container: </label>
                <select class="form-control" name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
                    <option selected value="widget">Widget</option>
                    <option value="graph">Graph</option>
                    <option value="table">Table</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="formSelectWidget" class="form-group">
                <label for="selectWidget">Data: </label>
                <select class="form-control" name="selectWidget" id="selectWidget">
                    <option value="live">Live</option>
                    <option value="alerts">Alerts</option>
                    <option value="energy">Energy</option>
                    <option class="d-none" value="liveAndAverages">Live and averages</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please include the `formSelectColour` element in your demonstration as well, so that the code makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `toggleClass` in these situations. It accepts an add/remove flag something like:

```
$(function () {
    $("#selectBox").on("change", function () {
        var is_widget = $("#selectBox").val() === "widget"; 
        if (!is_widget)
            $("#selectWidget").val("live");
        $("#formSelectColour").toggleClass("d-none", !is_widget);
        $('#selectWidget option[value="liveAndAverages"]').toggleClass("d-none", !is_widget);
        $('#selectWidget option[value="energy"]').toggleClass("d-none", is_widget);
        $('#selectWidget option[value="alerts"]').toggleClass("d-none");
    });
});
```